# Matlab, averaging y values based on x =1

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am having trouble averaging y values based on their x counter parts.

For example

1 5

3 4

1 6

How do I get 5 and 6 to average based on being paired with an x value of 1? For my specific issue I will have 98 values between repeating 1's, and there will be a total of 99 1's in the array.

This is not extremely complicated, but it has been over a year since I have used matlab so being rusty has me scratching my head.

Comment: Is this a `matlab` specific question? If so, remove the `C++` tag.

Comment: _"I learned matlab in c++"_ What does this mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got:

```
x = [1, 5;
     3, 4;
     1, 6]

col1 = x(:, 1) % extract first row

col1 =

   1
   3
   1

ri = find(col1 == 1) % get row indices where 1 appears

ri =

   1
   3

mean(x(ri, 2)) % index into the second column of rows with a 1, and take average

ans =  5.5000
```

Comment: or skip the call to find and use logical indexing, `mean(x(col1 == 1, 2))`

Comment: eh if you want to save a line go ahead, it's not likely to make a huge difference. OP has stated that he hasn't used Matlab in >year, so I wanted to provide for clarity